# How can I change the width of RibbonApplicationMenuItem in wpf?

Tags: wpf, ribbon

In a WPF Ribbon Application(.Net Framework 4), How we can change the width of a RibbonApplicationMenuItem when the menu application appears?

Answer (score 0):

```
<r:RibbonDropDownButton >
<Label Content="Column Header1" Style="{StaticResource CatHeader}" />
<UniformGrid Columns="2">
     <r:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Item1" Width="x"/>
     ... where x=value and so on
</UniformGrid>
```